# Set multiple images to multiple PictureBoxs

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

what I intend to do is

```
  PictureBox1.Image = ImageHere
```

But I am not sure how I would go about this on mass other than then

```
  PictureBox2.Image = ImageHere2
  PictureBox3.Image = ImageHere3
  PictureBox4.Image = ImageHere4
```

If I could just do [increment] or something but that gets rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to put the picture boxes and the images into arrays or the likes of it, you could loop like this:

```
PictureBox[] pictureBoxes = { PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4 };
Image[] images = { ImageHere1, ImageHere2, ImageHere3, ImageHere4 };

for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    pictureBoxes[i].Image = images[i];
}
```

There's still the hassle of creating the arrays though.

Comment: is there a way to add images to this image array?

Comment: nevermind about ^ and this was perfect for what i was looking for since i am still "new" to coding, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create your pictureboxes and assign them corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of images and use foreach iterator:

```
List<Image> images = //get your list of images
foreach(var img in images)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = img;
    YourControl.Add(pb);
}
```

Comment: I do not know exactly where you need to show your picturebox. YourControl.Add - is your add method to the control where your picturebx needs to be shown, while as soon as pb is created at runtime - it will not be shown on yur form, etc before you add it to it.